# How can I make an erc20votes token an interchain token using axelar?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, axelar

I’m trying to make a token interchain, my token is an erc20votes token

I tried deploying the ERC20votes contract through the interchain token portal, registered it on avalanche as the main chain, and deployed to the bnb chain as a remote chain, all the functions work fine on the main chain (avalanche) and I was able to send tokens crosschain from avalanche to bnb, but when I test the erc20votes contract on the bnb chain (remote chain) and try to call some functions on it that are not native to the IERC20 interface like `delegate`, the transaction fails and I get this error after debugging from remix

`Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"The method \"debug_traceTransaction\" does not exist / is not available.","id":7108126628519236}`

How can I make the erc20votes token interchain so that I can call `delegate` and some other functions on the erc20votes contract on the remote chains?

I tried using the axelar interchain portal to make it interchain, I expected the call to go through, but the transaction reverts.

Answer (score 1):

To make your token available with all of your custom functionality on multiple chains, you'll want to register a custom `TokenManager` on each chain by calling this method on the Interchain Token Service (0xF786e21509A9D50a9aFD033B5940A2b7D872C208):

```
function deployCustomTokenManager(
    bytes32 salt,
    TokenManagerType tokenManagerType,
    bytes memory params
) public payable notPaused returns (bytes32 tokenId)
```

You'll need to give the token manager permissions to mint/burn or lock/release (on up to one chain). By sharing a caller address and a salt, the token ID should match across chains and your tokens should flow when you call the sending methods on the TokenManager.